# Pandas: Change name of the row indices "column" without adding a new level of indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to change the name in the red outline to 'IDX' without creating a new index level. I have that name in there after grouping by 'SEXEDESCRIPCIO' in a previous df, unstacking and resetting indices.

[Dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0tUV.png)

So far I have tried with rename_axis, df.index.rename and df.rename with a dictionary but I have either created a new index level or produced no result at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean you need to change the name of the index / the column name?

Comment: You should supply the DataFrame in your post. You can format your code by putting tripple ` at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: That looks like a column rather than an index. You can try doing `df = df.rename(columns={'SEXEDESCRIPCIO': 'IDX'})`

Answer (score 0):

Here you find your DataFrame, the first two lines:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'MUNICIPIDESCRIPCIO':['Abrera', 'Agramunt'], 'Dona':[214.0, 104.0], 'Home':[151.0, 118.0], 'CasosTotal':[365, 222]}, index=pd.Series([0,1], name='SEXEDESCRIPCIO'))
```

If you want to rename the index, the following works:

```
df.index.name = 'Newname'
```